# Syntax error in FROM clause - MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am working with a tool that would extract some data from an Access Database. So basically, i am working on a query to get this data.

Below is the code i am currently working on.

I am getting an error: `Syntax error in FROM clause`

I can't seem to find where the query is going wrong. I would appreciate any help! Thank youu.

**EDIT:** putting my actual query

```
SELECT table_freq.*, IIF(table_freq.txn_ctr > (table_ave_freq.ave_freq * 3), "T", "F") as suspicious_flag
FROM

    (
        SELECT tbl_TransactionHistory.client_num, tbl_TransactionHistory.client_name, 
            tbl_TransactionHistory.transaction_date, Count(tbl_TransactionHistory.client_num) AS txn_ctr
        FROM tbl_TransactionHistory
        GROUP BY tbl_TransactionHistory.client_num, tbl_TransactionHistory.client_name, 
            tbl_TransactionHistory.transaction_date
    ) AS table_freq

INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT table_total_freq.client_num, total_txn_ctr as TotalTransactionFrequency, total_no_days as TotalTransactionDays,
                (table_total_freq.total_txn_ctr)/(table_no_of_days.total_no_days) AS ave_freq
        FROM 
        (
            (
                SELECT client_num, SUM(txn_ctr) AS total_txn_ctr
                FROM 
                (
                    SELECT client_num, client_name, transaction_date, COUNT(client_num) AS txn_ctr 
                    FROM tbl_TransactionHistory 
                    GROUP BY client_num, client_name, transaction_date
                )  AS tabFreq
                GROUP BY client_num
            ) AS table_total_freq


        INNER JOIN 
            (
                SELECT client_num, COUNT(txn_date) as total_no_days
                FROM
                (   
                    SELECT DISTINCT(transaction_date) as txn_date, client_num
                    FROM tbl_TransactionHistory
                    ORDER BY client_num
                ) AS table1
                GROUP BY client_num
            ) AS table_no_of_days

            ON table_total_freq.client_num = table_no_of_days.client_num
        )
    ) AS table_ave_freq

    ON table_freq.client_num = table_ave_freq.client_num
```

Comment: Do you actually have a select statement where it says 'SELECT STATEMENT' ?

Comment: nope. i just didn't put the whole select statement.

Comment: It says you have a syntax error in your from clause, so you probably want to include all of it.

Comment: i'll update my question. will put my actual query

Comment: Put this SQL into the SQL view of an Access query, and try to run it. When the error message is displayed, a part of the SQL will be selected. This should help finding the wrong part.

Comment: `ORDER BY client_num` in the sub-query?